# Display the UItableView index to the left of table instead of right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using Indexed UITableView by implementing the following delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

The index is displayed on the right of the table.
I was wondering if the index can be displayed on the left instead.

Thanks,

Comment: Please check this link, might be helpful. https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the style and position of this index is not configurable (unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

You can move the tableView index view to the left, but just a little bit so you don't get your app rejected )). Here is how:

```
// somewhere in your code for example in table view delegate method add this code
// take the index view, which is the last subview on the tableView
UIView *indexView = [[self.tableView subviews]lastObject];

// now take its frame and play with it
CGRect indexViewRect = indexView.frame;
indexViewRect.origin.x -= 50;      // move it to the left by -50
indexView.frame = indexViewRect;   // set the new frame
```

Thats it :)

By the way, I dont think Apple will reject your app if you move the index view to the most left, because I saw this on their contacts app on the iPad, but anyway at your risk.

Update: Fully customizable and easy to use ScrollBar you can find here: 
https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Comment: You are missing an opening bracket in set indexView, but thanks for the help.

Comment: I have a better solution for you guys, check this free code its will solve all your problems and more. https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the api exposes that component.  So sadly, you'd have to suppress rotations and hold the phone upside down, and this would be a very poor user experience.  (Just a joke, don't downvote me)

Answer (score 1):

Even not officially exposed by iOS APIs, it *should* be possible to move the index, by "hacking" a bit.

First you have to locate the the index in the UITableView subviews tree.
One simple way to do this is to put a breakpoint at runtime and use that:

```
 po [myTableView recursiveDescription]
```

This will print the views tree and by analyzing it you should find a way to programmatically find the UIView that interests you and just move it (`view.frame.origin`), and that, *without using any private API*

But before trying this, think twice. That index is on right side for a good reason, most people are right handed with the thumb on that right side... It would be hard to use on other side.